# Android Custom View Two Way binding not working with LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

I have a problem regarding livedata in custom views in android, I have a custom class with a text livedata that is two-way binded to the xml but the problem is that whenever the user writes any new value in the TextInputEditText the value of livedata is not changed.

```
class MaterialTextInput @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : MaterialCardView(context, attrs) {

    val viewModel = MaterialTextInputViewModel()

    init {
        ViewMaterialTextInputBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true
        ).apply {
            viewModel = this@MaterialTextInput.viewModel
        }
    }

    class MaterialTextInputViewModel : ViewModel() {
        var text = MutableLiveData("")
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.app.utils.views.MaterialTextInput.MaterialTextInputViewModel" />
    </data>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cardContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:strokeColor="@{viewModel.text.length() > 0 ? @color/color_4 : @color/white}"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/email_address"
            app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
            app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/textField"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="@={viewModel.text}" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</layout>
```

Comment: Why do you have `ViewModel` inside `View` ? And which lifecycle its attached to > how do you create it ?

Comment: This is the problem actually, I want to make custom view but using MVVM and viewModels, no lifecycle is attached now, how should this be solved?

Comment: There is no point of having a VM inside of a view . Just create the view and expose setter methods and call them from your component i.e activity or fragment whichever it is ..

Comment: I want to make use of two way binding and listen to text change for changing view stroke color, Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Create a callback which will provide changes to the component then further set it to live data from your component. That's the way it should be I guess to keep views independent of everything else.

Comment: Have you fixed that @BishoyN.Gendy